# Menu overlapping the body

Tags: css, html, overlap

I am  facing with a problem that my top menu overlaps the body. When actually menu must be placed above body.
I've already tried `display: block;` but it didn't help

Can you look trough it please ?

Here my **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bfqe2/3/)**

Comment: you need to tell your problem a bit more in depth. what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Dude Make your Question more clearly.

Comment: Menu on the top is placed ON the body (overlaps it), when it must be placed above. Something like this

Comment: Do you want the menu to stay in the same position on screen regardless of scroll? This would be fixed position http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed

Comment: Not exactly, i've edited the description and example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, try this. Give the menu div

```
style="display:table;"
```

and hope it will solve your issue. Before it doesnot assume any space for div itself, but only for the content and the main div occupies the space right from the top.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfqe2/5/). I have given there inline css. But I suggest to define a class for menu and put the css in there.

Comment: I have changed the code if you'd like to look it trough. Sorry, forgot to get rig of all unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a container div for the entire page? And then have a background div and a separate menu div?

```
<div id="page_container">
 <div id="background"> Background code
  <div id="menu">Menu code
  </div>
  <div id="body_content">Content in body code
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, but it didnt seem to help